# Undefined reference when trying to reference figure from within appendix file

Tags: cross-referencing, appendix

I have created a separate appendix file and have some figures in this file. I am trying to reference these figures in the text contained in the same file. However, I get undefined reference in the output file - ?? instead of the figure number. I also made sure that my caption for each figure was defined before the corresponding label. Moreover, it worked properly when I had it all in the main file (before I created a separate appendix). Here is my code - I have removed the content and only kept the formatting.

## Main file:

```
 \documentclass[aps,pra,twocolumn,showpacs,amsmath,amssymb,preprintnumbers,superscriptaddress,10pt]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[bookmarks=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\crefname{section}{Sec.}{Secs.}% APS style uses abbreviations
\Crefname{section}{Section}{Sections}
\usepackage[retainplus]{siunitx}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % for the \sout command. Delete when finalized
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}


\begin{document}

\begin{appendices}
    \include{Appendix_A}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

## Appendix file (titled Appendix_A):

```
\section{Appendix} 
                                                                                       
Figure\ref{fig.PMF} shows something.

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=0.90\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption[content 1]{content 2}
\end{figure}\label{fig.PMF}
```

Comment: `\label` has to be inside the `figure` (unrelated to appendix markup) (although the markup shown  would produce the wrong reference rather than undefined reference warning) it is always better to post a complete small document that shows the problem, as it is impossible to debug your fragments of code.

Comment: Changed it. The above code reproduces the error. You would need to have a file called "PMF.pdf" in  your working directory to run it.

Comment: you can use `example-image` as the image which is generally available for tests or in this case simply delete the `\includegraphics` as the reference does not need an image, just a caption.

Comment: thanks for the test case, that's weird, looking now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the test file to

```
\documentclass[aps,pra,twocolumn,showpacs,amsmath,amssymb,
           preprintnumbers,superscriptaddress,10pt]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}


\begin{document}

\begin{appendices}
    \include{Appendix_A}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

there seems to be a bad interaction here with revtex and the appendix package  which ends up breaking the `\include` mechanism. If you change that to

```
\input{Appendix_A}
```

Then it all works as intended.

Comment: Thanks very much. That worked. I also placed the label inside the figure handle because it showed the wrong reference.